# Creating Custom Angular Button Component with Disabled Attribute

Tags: javascript, angular

I was wondering how it would be possible for me to create a custom Angular component that was based off of the native HTML button element and contained its own `disabled` property.

We currently have our own implementation of the `button` element that does not contain a `disabled` property and I wanted to know how I can add this functionality and make sure that it remains unusable and un-clickable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  template: `<button [disabled]="disabledValue">button</button>`
})
export class MyButtonComponent  {
@Input()
public disabledValue: boolean;
}
//usage: <my-button [disabledValue]="true"><my-button/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Out of curiosity, if you are planning on extending some native HTML elements functionality, would you normally just wrap your component around it and add to it?

Comment: actually, not :)
you can use [disabled]="true" (or false) directly on button.